# How to fix PCH warning: header stop cannot be in a linkage block vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-extensions

In vscode, after creating a c++ project from a template then removing all the template code and replacing with my own, I ran into the error `PCH warning: header stop cannot be in a linkage block` appearing as an error on one of my #include statements.

There are a few other SO focused on this topic, but many recommend changing code to include `#pragma once` or other such changes which modify the code itself. As this seems to be an intellisense issue, I want to know a fix to this that does not involve the code itself. This can be very bothersome as it seems to block other intellisense features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the best fix I could find is to turn off `C_Cpp.intelliSenseCacheSize` by setting it to `0` in your workspace settings json. I discovered this from [this GitHub issue on the topic](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3341).

Adding this line

```json
...
"settings": {
   "C_Cpp.intelliSenseCacheSize": 0,
...
```

to your `.code-workspace` file seems to fix it. Might need to reload vscode to be safe.

As far as why this helps, I think that (especially in cases where I was using a template to start) I think it has to do with this line from the GitHub issue:

> IntelliSense will auto generate precompiled headers (PCH) if there are any #include header files that it can cache.

So it must be precompiling a header from the template that is removed and left hanging because it was the only header to begin with, or something like that. in 2019 there was a comment that this would likely be removed in a future version.

Comment: Yes, I too found that post.  Looks like it fell through the cracks.

Comment: intelliSense cache will use a large portion of your disk for each C++ project